# Easy database userface

Tags: sql-server, database, sharepoint, ms-office

I have a simple SQL Server database that we use for conversions. Basically a table with two mor more columns where one value maps to another. We then have processes that use these tables to find matching values and select other values on that row.

These values change a lot and we now need a interface for the business users to update the values themselves. I ***don't*** want to spend time building something new, I rather use and interface that the uses are used to - for example Excel or something in SharePoint.

Have you solved something similar and what your idea for a easy win in the scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily [create a connection from Excel](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HA101672271033.aspx) to let them use *their preferred tool* to do the updates ;-)

**Edit**: Apparently, the above link doesn't make it possible to update the changes back to SQL Server (automatically).
While searching for a solution this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750565/writing-data-back-to-sql-from-excel-sheet) came up... It seems you have to do some manual work...
[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa192473.aspx) I found an even better link with a walkthrough for what you're trying to do. HTH

Comment: But I guess a connection like this doesn't enabling updating the data in the tables?

Answer (score 1):

You can map the SQL Server table into an Access "table" (I forget the exact Access term for this "table" type.)

Result will be that your users can use the Access tools, including the grid, to change the data on the actual server.

Remember to create user names on the SQL Server that only have the minimum permissions needed to do the valid tasks. Eg do the users need insert or delete ability on the rows? Or just update ability?

Larry

Comment: I think they call them linked tables.  You are right, this is probably the easiest way to handle this.  Especially if the users are already comfortable with Access.

Comment: Is it called a "linked table" in Access?

Answer (score 1):

You could either use [ASP.Net Dynamic Data scaffolding](http://www.asp.net/dynamicdata/) or use the Business Data Catalog if you have MOSS 2007 Enterprise with some off-the-shelf web parts which enable write-back capability.

Answer (score -1):

I think Acces is better than Excel for this purpose as you can create the code to really limit what they can use as acceptable values much more easily.

Another possiblility is a web-based form (or application depending on how complex this is) that you create in .net or some other language depending on what you know. As long as they have the web address and the form is fairly straightforward, your users will have no trouble with this. Make it available only  on the intranet and not to the outside world and require usernames and passwords and it is as secure as the other possibilites being floated around. One real advantage of this is that when change time comes around you can easliy deply changes. One disadvantage is it is more complex to originally set up than an Access form.